# Where to find Microsoft's epcis class

Tags: c#

I use Visual Studio Community edition. I'm working on a project where I generate a unique string that is printed onto a carton.

My customer has specified the GS1 marking system and their EPCIS tracking system.

I found information on a C# Class that covers this EPCIS standard, its described as **Microsoft.sensorservices.rfid.epcis**

I'm having trouble finding this class, not sure if its something I can purchase or download.

Can anyone help?

Thanks J

Comment: From what I understand, you're looking a program that generates random sentenced.  Right?

Comment: Take a look here https://sourceforge.net/p/epicssharp/wiki/Home/ and http://epics.web.psi.ch

Comment: No, I'm looking for a copy of the epcis class to use in my c# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it in Windows folder, but only for:

Development Platforms

> Windows Small Business Server 2003 with SP2; The 32-bit and 64-bit
>   editions of Windows Server 2003 R2 (except the Web Editions); The
>   32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2003 SP2 (except the Web
>   Edition); The 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008
>   (except the Web Server Editions); The 32-bit and 64-bit editions of
>   Windows Vista Ultimate, Enterprise and Business editions with Service
>   Pack 1; The 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows XP Professional with
>   Service Pack 3

Target Platforms

> Windows Small Business Server 2003 with SP2; The 32-bit and 64-bit
>   editions of Windows Server 2003 R2 (except the Web Editions); The
>   32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2003 SP2 (except the Web
>   Edition); The 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008
>   (except the Web Server Editions); The 32-bit and 64-bit editions of
>   Windows Vista Ultimate, Enterprise and Business editions with Service
>   Pack 1; The 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows XP Professional with
>   Service Pack 3

you can try to find `microsoft.rfid.epcis.dll` somewhere

p.s you are trying to use obsolete technology